# How can I send a variable from an Electron html file to a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Im trying to get a number input from a form on the html document, and then send it to the javascript document and console.log it. Even while trying to debug and trying multiple versions it still wont work.

**HTML DOC:**

```js
<form id="searchForm" onsubmit="search(event)" class="nodrag">
    <input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="COMING SOON">
    <input type="submit" value="O-">
</form>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>
    function search(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const query = document.getElementById('searchBar').value;
        ipcRenderer.send('search-query', query);
    }
</script>
```

**INDEX.JS :**

```js
const {ipcMain, app, BrowserWindow, remote } = require('electron');
let num = 0;

//code to create electron window

const checkForUpdates = () => {
    ipcMain.on('search-query', (query) => {
        console.log(`Received search query: ${query}`);
    });
}
setInterval(checkForUpdates, 300);
```

Im sorry that I can't provide further information on why it doesnt work as everything looks fine to me. I can provide more information regarding the html and javascript files if needed.

Comment: Is this your real code? Because your application shouldn't even start with this syntax error you've got here (comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`). If it's not your real code, please provide a (working) [mcve] of your problem. Meanwhile, please read up on [ask] and possibly [edit] your question. "It doesn't work" is not all too helpful. Thanks!

Comment: yes it is, i just added those specifically for this question (not in my actual code) because i just wanted to grab peoples' attention to let them know that my code for creating a wind is there. Also "it doesnt work" is the most that i'm aware i can give you. it produces no errors, and it seems to take the input as it does away when i enter, but thats pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an old version of Electron to be utilising the `remote` module. This was withdrawn some time ago. Though there is a userland `remote` module, it is best to avoid it's use through better application design where possible.

To implement a well-structured Electron application one needs to read and understand Electron's best practices when it comes to communicating between your render processes and your main process(es).

For more information regarding this, see the below listed links:

- [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)
- [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)
- [Using Preload Scripts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload)
- [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge)
- [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer)
- [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main)

---

Regarding the rest of your code.

- In your `index.js`(main process) file (which below I call `main.js`), there is no need to implement a `setInterval()` function to poll `ipcMain.on('search-query, () => {});`. Instead, just include the `ipcMain.on()` function in the normal flow of your code, as IPC will trigger the function when a message is received on that channel.

As everything else appears to be in order, let's create a minimum reproducible example to show you how it all works together with use of a `preload.js` script.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('search', (event, searchValue) => {
    console.log(searchValue);
})
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From render to main
        search: (searchValue) => {
            ipcRenderer.send('search', searchValue);
        }
    }
);
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="searchForm" class="modrag">
            <label for="search">Search: </label>
            <input type="search" id="search">

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('searchForm').addEventListener('submit', () => {
            window.ipcRenderer.search(document.getElementById('search').value);
        })
    </script>
</html>
```